# SPSS how to find the probability that mean is greater than x when y is equal to z

Tags: statistics, probability, spss

I have a set of data that has the marks of students for each class they're enrolled in (each class is in its own column along with there corresponding marks). I'm trying to make some useful stats out of this, how would I go about calculating the probability of a female student (gender is also its own column) getting 40% or more in their biology class? How do I go about making queires where I can compare the marks and the gender of my students? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a `TEMPORARY` command to only select females and then generate your summary table of interest. Such as (replace with your own variable names):

```
TEMPORARY.
SELECT IF gender = 'F'.
FREQ biology.
```

From the frequency table you will be able to gather the requested statistic via the cumulative probability column.